# Will wearing heavy armour gauntlets with light armour set affect my sneaking?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was planning to start wearing Daedric or Ebony Gauntlets with my Nightingale Armour, I will obviously be wearing the Nightingale Hood / Chest armour and Boots. Will wearing the Heavy Armour gauntlets like Daedric affect my sneaking or stealth character in any way?

Comment: Nightingale boots have muffle on them, don't they?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is:  **wearing heavier gauntlets does make a difference, but it's not that big of a deal.**

The UESP page for [Sneak](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Sneak) lists the things that effect sneak chance, and among them is the weight of your armor:

> Sneaking is affected by the combined weight of all your armor, not just your boots (unlike in Oblivion)

Heavy armor tends to weigh more than light armor, so it has a chance to effect your sneak success rate.  However, Daedric gauntlets weigh 6 pounds (and gives 18 "base" armor without any further smithing improvements), which is only 3 more  than Dragonscale (at 12 "base" armor).

At a high sneak level, I never really found that noise was that much of an issue.  Additionally, the Nightingale boots come with a built-in muffle enchantment that reduces or eliminates noise, based on the level you were when you earned them.

If you earned the Nightingale boots early (prior to [level 32](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Nightingale_Boots)) and they lack the magnitude of enchantment to make you fully silent, you have other muffle options.  Enchanting boots with this spell makes you completely silent (but you'll lose the Nightingale set bonus), or you could use the Muffle spell for situations where noise is an issue.